# Using PoSh KeePass in Dollar Universe

Tags: powershell, automation, keepass

I am trying to use a Powershell Script that would get started by Dollar Universe. However, for accessing some services I need user credentials which are saved in a KeePass DB.

To access the KeePass DB I have to create a KeePass secret like this:

```
New-KeePassTempPhrase -TempPhrase "xyz" -MasterPassword "abc"
```

I tried to crete this secret in a normal Powershell session and as a Powershell script that gets called by Dollar Universe. This step doesn't produce any errors. However when I want to run my script afterwards I get the following error:

```
 Find-KeePassEntry : The secret for xyz no longer exists
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to implement KeePass in a Powershell run by Dollar Universe or maybe already have the solution for this problem?

Comment: According to sources of PoSh Keepass those temp phrases are stored in %Appdata%\BadMishka\tmp\keepass. You could check if this folder is writable/accessible (it should be).

Comment: You could try this [PoShKeePass](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoShKeePass/2.1.3.0) module, its configs are all local to the module folder and supports much more functionality.